# android playing audio stream to default or installed music player

Tags: android

I am developing an app where I can stream audio from http get requests and play it to the default android music player or installed music player? I have no idea how to do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do this way

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.example.com/file.mp3");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                startActivity(intent);
```